# search through a List with a Comma separated string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

```
I have a comma separated string FacultyList="1,2,3,4...1004,1005..."
```

Then there is a List of applicants of type "InitialApplicantModel". FacultyList is a property of InitialApplicantModel.

```
public class InitialApplicantModel
{
  public int applicantID {get;set}
  public string FacultyList {get; set;}
}
```

I want to get a list of applicants where their FacultyList contains the value 4.

> EX: applicantID 1 has the FacultyList=1,2,30,4,..100 / applicantID 2 has
>   the FacultyList=200,301,.... / applicant 3 has the
>   FacultyList=101,2,31,4,..110

So the final list should return applicant 1 and 3.

I tried the code below but doesn't seem to return the correct result.

```
foreach (InitialApplicantModel item in applicants)
{
    if (item.FacultyList != null)
    {
        string[] array = item.FacultyList.Split(',');
        array = array.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
        applicants = applicants.AsEnumerable().Where(o => array.Any(b =>(b)== "4")).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense, you're never even inspecting the application (`o`) in your where call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need [Where()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549418(v=vs.100).aspx) method to filter datas as you want. These method accepts anonymous method as input. These method must return boolean value. Inside this method, you must split the value by `','` and then search if the returned array contains `4` or not.

```
var result = applicants
             .Where(x => x.FacultyList.Split(',').Contains("4"))
             .ToList();
```

*Update1*:
If the string is null, `.Split()` will  throw a `NullReferenceException`.

```
var result = applicants
             .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.FacultyList) ?     
                          x.FacultyList.Split(',').Contains("4") : false)
             .ToList();
```

*Update2*:

```
var result = applicants
             .Where(x => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.FacultyList) ?     
                          x.FacultyList.Split(',').Equals("4") : false)
             .ToList();
```

Comment: Can you pick one of your answers that you would like to keep, and delete the other?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev First I need to check if FacultyList is null. is there a way to check it without using the foreach loop?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev what if the array item has items like 44,104.. contains will take them also as valid items right? but I need the item to be matched exactly with "4"

Comment: @chamara In the question you have said that **contains** 4. So, I have answered in that way. But, if you want to check if the string equals to 4, then see my new Update.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `foreach` loop:

```
applicants = applicants
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(o => o.FacultyList.Split(',').Contains("4")).ToList();
```

Comment: First I need to check if FacultyList is null. is there a way to check it without using the foreach loop?